# How to specify image size as percentage relative to page size in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook

The corresponding option has been present in the image size dialog of Word for many years, but it is always grayed out:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/H7LrDiQ.png]

Any ideas how this option could be activated?

Answer (score 2):

It activates only if you want to change the size of an object, not an image as mentioned [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/set-relative-size-of-an-image/a22b83c5-d098-4c8c-a68e-f6c92a2ef5eb):

> The Relative Size settings only pertain to 'Drawing Objects' (AutoShapes).  The do not apply to photographs, Clip Art or other images unless they are Grouped with a Shape.

**Format AutoShape window**

[image]

You will have to add the image inside a shape and modified the shape size as indicated in the [aforementioned link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/set-relative-size-of-an-image/a22b83c5-d098-4c8c-a68e-f6c92a2ef5eb).

> Copy the picture, draw a shape (e.g. a rectangle), right-click > Format Shape > File & Line > Fill > Picture or Texture Fill > Insert picture from: Clipboard.
>
> You can then right-click on the shape > More layout options > Size tab > and the relative options should now be enabled.

Comment: Thanks, the Shape workaround works -- however only for shapes that are not in an inline position. Strangely, Word does not even show an image with 100% width if the page is coded in HTML and opened in Word.